# ios - get values from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I have JSON on my server, which is parsed into iOS app to NSDictionary. NSDictionary looks like this:

```
(
        {
        text = Aaa;
        title = 1;
    },
        {
        text = Bbb;
        title = 2;
    }
)
```

My question is - how to get just text from first dimension, so it should be "Aaa". I've tried to use this:

```
[[[json allValues]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];
```

But it didn't work, it ends with error

> ```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allValues]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x714a050'
> ```

So can you help me please, how to get just one value from specified index? Thanks!

Comment: are you comming from PHP with it's ugly array-dictionary hotchpotch?

Comment: What you have is an array containing two dictionaries.  The "()" characters indicate an array.

Comment: It was from my example... But don't care, I've soved it.. :-) (thanks to Ramy Al Zuhouri)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON object is an array, containing two dictionaries. That's how to get the values:

```
NSDictionary* dict1= json[0];
NSString* text= dict1[@"text"];
NSString* title= dict1[@"title"];
```

Comment: still getting this error :( 


Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71571b0'

Comment: @stepik21 Sorry you hadn't to send an allValues message, I edited the answer, try again :-)

Answer (score 6):

That error message is simply telling you that `NSDictionary` (which is the first object of that array, along with the second) doesn't respond to `objectAtIndex`.

This will be a bit cody, but it explains it better:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [json allValues];
NSDictionary *firstObjectDict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myValue = [firstObjectDict valueForKey:@"text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *txt = [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"text"];
```

**UPDATE:** Have fixed the error. Thanks yunas.

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8892320'

Comment: @stepik21 : Please share how are you parsing the json. You should also test if variable json is infact an NSDictionary. Try this NSLog(@"%@",[json desc]);

Comment: I'm using this: 

json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com"]] options:kNilOptions error:&e];

but never mind, I've solved it :-)

Comment: [json allValues] why do you need that ? [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"text"] does the job